# Is it possible to use an unbound type as a generic type parameter in C#?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a C# generic:

```
public class Generic<TParameter> { ... }
```

It does not appear that I can use unbound types as type parameters. I get `error CS1031: Type expected` when I try the following:

```
var lGenericInstance = new Generic<List<>>();
```

How can I use an unbound type as a generic type parameter? Are there workarounds? My generic class is just using reflection so I can get a list of the provided type's members as strings.

---

**Update:** My question about the unbound type has been answered, so I have followed up with a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366760/get-a-generics-member-names-as-strings-without-knowing-the-type-parameters) that addresses my specific problem.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you are trying to accomplish; as a general rule the answer would be no, you cannot instantiate a generic with out specifying it's type parameters.  But maybe there's a better answer to your specific problem.

Comment: That construct is not legal. The only place you can (typically) use an unbound generic is `typeof(List<>)`.

Comment: You can create `new Generic<IList>` (non-generic list). If you're not supplying a type, there is no need for the generic list in the first place, I'd think.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Foo<T> { }
class Bar<T> { }

Type unboundBar = typeof(Bar<>);
Type unboundFoo = typeof(Foo<>);
Type boundFoo = unboundFoo.MakeGenericType(new[] { unboundBar });
Console.WriteLine(boundFoo.Name);
Conosle.WriteLine(boundFoo.GetGenericArguments().First().Name);
```

Note that you can't write

```
Type boundFoo = typeof(Foo<Bar<>>)
```

because the specification explicitly states:

> An unbound generic type can only be used within a *typeof-expression* (§7.6.11).

(`Bar<>` is not being used as a parameter to the *typeof-expression* here, rather, it's a generic type parameter to the parameter to a *typeof-expression*.)

However, it's perfectly legal within the CLR, as the above using reflection shows.

But what are you trying to do? You can't have instances of unbound types, so I don't get it.

Comment: mmmh... Can you create something like he wanted ( var lGenericInstance = new Generic<List<>>(); ) with this approach?

Comment: @Davide Piras: It's not possible to have instances for types where `ContainsGenericParameters` is `true`.

Comment: @The commenter that suggested using: `typeof(Foo<Bar<>>)`. No, that's not possible. It's verboten by the specification.

Comment: @Jason Yes, I realized that. Thus the deletion :)

Comment: What if I want to have an open constructed type? Assuming a `Foo<T1, T2>` I want to get equivalent of `Foo<, Bar<>>`. Is that possible in a similar way?

Answer (score 2):

the question you are asking is in my opinion wrongly formulated.

the error you have in your code is because you cannot have `List<>` anywhere as it requires a type to be provided.

this one: `var lGenericInstance = new Generic<List<>>();` fails on `List`, not on `Generic`... well on both because they are chained... :)

so your question is more like:

why cannot I create an object of type `List<>` ? or why can't I specify `List<>` as T for my generic class?