# Get a generic's member names as strings without knowing the type parameters

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I'm using reflection to get some member names as strings. I'm using a method I found [on Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/gim-projects/source/browse/presentations/CantDanceTheLambda/src/MemberNameParser.cs) (but I don't have a strong grasp of the reflection/LINQ magic it uses):

```
public static class MembersOf<T> {
    public static string GetName<R>(Expression<Func<T,R>> expr) {
        var node = expr.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(null, node)) 
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Expression must be of member access");
        return node.Member.Name;
    }
}
```

This works great in static constructors. I just use it like this:

```
using ClassMembers = MembersOf<MyClass>;

class MyClass
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }

    static MyClass
    {
        string lMyPropertyName = ClassMembers.GetName(x => x.MyProperty);
    }
}
```

With this approach you avoid misspelling member names in string literals and can use automatic refactoring tools. It's nice to have when implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`!

But now I have a generic class that I want to use in the same manner, and [I've learned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366440/is-it-possible-to-use-an-unbound-type-as-a-generic-type-parameter-in-c) that you can't use unbound types as generic type parameters:

```
using ClassMembers = MembersOf<MyGeneric<>>;

class MyGeneric<T> { }
```

What would be a good way to work around this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way would be to forget the `using` directive and just use the class directly:

```
string propName = MembersOf<MyGeneric<T>>.GetName(x => x.SomeProp);
```

Answer (score 1):

D'oh! The `using ClassMembers` alias was hiding the obvious. I just need to use `MembersOf<MyGeneric<T>>` directly in my class!

```
class MyGeneric<T>
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }

    static MyClass<T>
    {
        string lMyPropertyName = MembersOf<MyGeneric<T>>.GetName(x => x.MyProperty);
    }
}
```